# Stop from Visual Studio opening TFS WIQ files as Text

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, team-explorer

Previously my installation of Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 wre both opening WIQ files correctly - connecting to TFS and wunning the TFS Query. Now both are opening the WIQ file as plain XML.

Of course, I could reinstall Visual Studio to fix the problem.

But I am looking for tips toward a faster work-around. Has someone encountered this problem before? If so how did you fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

- File -> Open -> Open file
- Browse to the WIQ file
- Click the right hand end of the "Open" button (on the down-arrow)
- A menu appears - choose "Open with..."
- Choose this and a dialog appears
- Select the editor you wish to use (e.g. XML)
- Click "Set as default" so that this will be uised for any "Open" of a WIQ in future.
- OK.

(Of course, it might not work if the VSTS WIQ editor isn't connected in to this system)